# Could not build wheels for snowflake-connector-python which use PEP 517

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connector

I am getting the following error while trying to install snowflake connector pin Spyder IDE in Windows 10 Pro having python 3.8.3 and PIP version pip 20.2.2

"Failed building wheel for snowflake-connector-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for snowflake-connector-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly"

I am using pip install snowflake-connector-python

Comment: Please provide the OS (windoz? etc. and version), and version of Python and PiP.  I have a feeling you are on Python 3.8 and the Snowflake connector isn't certified for this version yet.  If so, you'll need to install 3.7 and use the connector on that version.

Comment: Hi Rich , i am trying it in Windows 10 pro with Python 3.8.3 and pip 20.2.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windoz w/ Python 3.8.x is currently a problem for the connector, I suggest you install 3.7.x in another location, PiP install the connector there until a new version of the connector is released that can be used in 3.8.x.

You may want to log the issue in Github as well, though I had someone with the same issue yesterday and I know Snowflake is working on it.

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues

Comment: It seems it's not supporting for python 3.8 even now